# Twilio error code 53103, unable to create room when running on localhost

Tags: localhost, twilio

When I kick off a room on localhost:3000, as soon as I click Join Room, I get a message: Unable to create room, error 53103.  I am having a hard time finding that error message in the documentation.  I found something about installing and running ngrok and opening the port, but I still get the same message.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alan, thank you for the response.  There were 3 of us working on this and we finally figured out that it was a credentials issue.  Once we got the credentials right, we didn't see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 53103 Error message in the Twilio Documentation. Also, look at your Twilio debugger (the bug icon in the upper right corner of the Twilio console), to see if there are any more details to be shared.

[53103: Unable to create Room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/53103)